# RESTful Get Request with Angular & NodeJS Express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I'm just following tutorials and figuring out how to handle get requests in NodeJS.

Here are snippets of my code:

NodeJS:

```
router.get('/test', function(request, response, next) {
    console.log("Received Get Request");
    response.jsonp({
        data: 'test'
    });
});
```

Angular:

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/test").
success(function(response) {
    alert("OK");
}).
error(function(response) {
    alert("FAIL");
});
```

If I try to access the link directly @ `localhost:3000/test`, I'm able to receive the JSON message correctly. But when I use angularJS $http call, the request always fails and I'll find this error in the network inspector (Response)

> SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

The reason for that is because the response is empty but the response code is 200 in both cases.

I've tried searching for hours but maybe someone can enlighten me on this?

Comment: Are you echoing or printing anything else in the response? One reason could be your JSON is malformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try and send 
res.send('test')

and then on your http request you can use 'then'

```
$http.get("http://localhost:3000/test").then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
})
```

unlike success, then will give you a complete object (with 'test' - string as res.data)

success will bring you only the data;

then will bring you the whole object (with the status and such)..

now about that jsonp .. it's used to override a json response. you could simply use 'res.json({data: 'test'})' and it should also work for you..

hope it helps

Comment: I've just tried making the above changes. The direct link has response (test) but the angular request does not receive any response (empty).

Comment: What is assigned to router variable?

Answer (score 0):

You're using jsonp in node, which you probably don't need to. This adds extra characters to the response and so the JSON parser fails to parse (that's what the error is telling you, the JSON is malformed)

Try changing the server to look like

```
response.json({
    data: 'test'
});
```

If you look in the Network pane of the developer tools, you should be able to see the raw response. It should look something like:

```
{"data" : "test"}
```